# How I Solve CPLEX Error 5002: 'q2429' is not convex.->

Tags: cplex

I trying to solve mixed-integer linear programming with CPLEX 12.8 OPL. It is a ready-mixed concrete dispatching problem that similar to job shop scheduling problem, but it showing error code :

Exception from IBM ILOG CPLEX: CPLEX Error  5002: 'q2429' is not convex.->.

Thank you so much in advance.

Natdanai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use CPO within OPL CPLEX. You may find a jobshop example in `CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl\sched_jobshop`.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you're solving a *mixed-integer linear program*. But that is not what CPLEX sees, as it tells you that you're trying to solve a *non-convex quadratic program*.

If you should really have a linear program instead of a quadratic one, you must have made a mistake in your formulation.

If it's expected that the objective is quadratic, then maybe the following can help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip_quadratic/02_introMIQP.html